# Python best way to customise a parent class method

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

I have a Python parent class called Player with the following method:

```
def get_text(self):
        '''Returns a formatted string describing the player's status'''
        # Create initial string with dice info
        text = (f' is rolling {self.num_dice} dice and'
                f' has {self.num_rerolls} rerolls')
        # If at least one status is true, append the status text
        if True in self.status.values():
            text += self._get_status_text()
        return text
```

I have a subclass called Attacker that wants to use this method but add the word 'Attacker' to the start of the String accordingly, so I have overidden the method in Attacker like so:

```
def get_text(self):
        '''Returns a formatted string describing the attacker's status'''
        return 'Attacker' + super().get_text()
```

My question is, the way I have implemented this here: is this the best/correct way? Or should my child class be calling the parent class method and sending a "chosen_start_word" param over or something instead?

It's not going to make much difference for this example but I have a few more complex methods in Attacker that do most of the stuff the overidden method in Player does...but with a few additions, and want to know best practices for approaching this.

Comment: This is definitely correct and nice way.

Comment: If the `Player().get_text()` method will never be run by itself, but always be part of a child class, then I would probably say taking a parameter is nicer. But otherwise, this is good.

Comment: @Lecdi actually that is the case. The Player class is actually never used directly. Only the sub classes (Attacker and Defender) are ever instantiated and have the methods called.